# Let the user decide if function returns an Exception or null

Tags: c#, exception, architecture, software-design

I am building an SDK that provides some GET-functions like:

*GetCustomerById* or *GetProductById* etc.

I have use cases where those functions should return null if the id is not found and other use cases where an exception should be thrown, because this would be unexpected behaviour.

My idea was to design my get-functions in a way, that the user of my SDK can decide himself how the function should behave.

My ideas are:

- Each function gets an optional parameter 'throwExceptionIfNotFound'. If this is true, my function will throw an Exception that my SDK exposes: ie. MySDKNotFoundException.
- Each function is split into two functions: `GetCustomerById and GetCustomerByIdOrThrow`. The Throw-Function will throw an exception that the SDK exposes like in the first approach.
- Each function is split into two functions with the same name and parameters, but one gets a generic parameter that defines the Exception that should be thrown if the id is not found: `GetCustomerById and GetCustomerById<ExceptionToThrow>`

The last approach is my favorite. The user of my SDK even has the flexibility to define his own Exception that should be thrown on not found.

What do you think about my three ideas? Any other ideas? Why should one use one over the other?

Comment: If the user defines the Exception type it can't have additional data (how should the method know how to add them?) . Even if you prefer it its sounds very uncommon and actually not very helpful. Beyond that all of that would work.

Comment: ```GetCustomerById``` and ```GetCustomerByIdOrThrow```, is the most sane option I can think of. It is quite clear, easy to understand, easy to implement, easy to use

Comment: I agree with Özgür - just have 2 separate methods.

Comment: Yet another alternative could be to group all functions which can't throw exceptions under `Safe`. Like `client.GetCustomerById` and `client.Safe.GetCustomerById`. Or have a top level separation `client` and `safeClient`

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that all three can be ok, though personally I would not go with the 3rd one since it limits a bit what you can do with the exception (for example provide user-defined error message, though it can be worked around with `Func<TException>` factory).

Personally I would go with two methods approach but there are another 2 variations worth considering:

1. The "Try" pattern (as in [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-int32-tryparse(system-string-system-int32@))) which can look like:

   ```
   bool TryGetCustomerById(IdType id, out Customer customer)
   ```
2. Another approach I found useful, but arguably it is more suited for "internal" usage than SDK - use different verbs for different cases, like `Find` for non-throwing version (which pairs nicely with [nullable references types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), so the return type is `Customer?`) and `Get` for throwing one. So signatures can look like:

   ```
   Customer GetCustomerById(IdType id); // throws
   Customer? FindCustomerById(IdType id) // does not throw
   ```

   But this one will require that customers understand the convention.